# setState() callback argument returned a Future in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, asynchronous, dart

I'm trying to run a statment with await inside a `setState` block, I added it inside another `Future<void>` function but still I need to add `async` on the `setState` to be able to run it .

here is my code :

```dart
setState(() async {
  chosenStations.clear();
  chosenStations.add(allStations[
  suggestions.indexOf(fromLocationName)]);
  _loading = true;
  chosenStations.add(allStations[
  suggestions.indexOf(toLocationName)]);
  await showingLines();
      });


  Future<void> showingLines() async {
    theLines.clear();
    theLines = await DatabaseServices().fetchingLinesData(
        chosenStations[0], chosenStations[1]);
  }
```

and I got this error :

```
Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error tells that you need to move all the asynchronous logic out of `setState` because `setState` used to update the UI after doing some work apart of its nature

so what you can do is to move the `showingLines` function out of `setState` and await it then update the UI with the new lines

```
await showingLines();
setState(() {
      chosenStations.clear();
      chosenStations.add(allStations[
      suggestions.indexOf(fromLocationName)]);
      _loading = true;
      chosenStations.add(allStations[
      suggestions.indexOf(toLocationName)]);
  });


Future<void> showingLines() async {
    theLines.clear();
    theLines = await DatabaseServices().fetchingLinesData(
        chosenStations[0], chosenStations[1]);
}
```

Note: you can use `setState` directly without filling it with any work,

```
await showingLines();
chosenStations.clear();
chosenStations.add(allStations[
suggestions.indexOf(fromLocationName)]);
_loading = true;
chosenStations.add(allStations[
suggestions.indexOf(toLocationName)]);

setState(() {});

Future<void> showingLines() async {
    theLines.clear();
    theLines = await DatabaseServices().fetchingLinesData(
        chosenStations[0], chosenStations[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is also caused when we use async in setState((){})

Example: `setState(() async{})` -- this can too cause this issue

To remove it use it with the function like,

```
onTapped: () async{
  ...
}
```